# Probability that the 4th defective item is the 20th item checked

Tags: probability

> The probability that a computer chip is defective is 0.025. If you check each computer chip one by one, what is the probability that the 4th defective chip is the 20th chip checked?

I did $0.025^4 0.975^{16}$ and also $\binom{20}{4} 0.025^4 0.975^{16}$, but neither of these gives the correct answer. I realize that none of these ensures the position of any of the chips (it could be that the first 4 chips checked are defective, and the next 16 are not). So how do I calculate the probability of something in a particular position? I know we don't care about the position of the first 3 defective chips, but how can you mathematically express the 4th chip in the 20th position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be exactly $3$ bad in the first $19$, and the $20$-th must be bad.

The probability that there are $3$ bad in the first $19$ is $\binom{19}{3}(0.025)^3(0.975)^{16}$. Given this happened, the probability the $20$-th is bad is $0.025$. Thus the required probability is $\binom{19}{3}(0.025)^4 (0.975)^{16}$.

For more information about the distribution, please search under *negative binomial*.